# Delete chrome.alarms listener in chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

In a chrome extension, it is very easy to create an alarm and add a listener to it with this sample code:

```
chrome.alarms.create(idAlarm, {
    when: dateAlarm,
    periodInMinutes: parseInt(repeatAlarm)
});
chrome.alarms.onAlarm.addListener(function (alarm) {
  //TODO with Listener (when alarm is activated)
)};
```

But, later, if I call

```
crome.alarms.clear(idAlarm);
```

The alarm is cleared but the listener is still active. What is the best way to remove a listener for a specific alarm "on the fly"?

I presume I must call `chrome.alarms.onAlarm.removeListener()` but did not found a way to make this call works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm definitely not an expert regarding chrome extensions (never wrote one), but looking at the docs I think you have to name the listener function and then do it like this:

```
function alarmListener(alarm) {
    if (alarm == "myAlarmIdentifier") {
        // Do stuff.
    }
}
chrome.alarms.create("myAlarmIdentifier", {
    when: dateAlarm,
    periodInMinutes: parseInt(repeatAlarm)
});
chrome.alarms.onAlarm.addListener(alarmListener);
```

Then to delete the alarm and [remove the listener](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/events#method-Event-removeListener):

```
chrome.alarms.clear("myAlarmIdentifier");
chrome.alarms.onAlarm.removeListener(alarmListener);
```

Comment: Thanks Max. My problem: the callback for addListener event is a function as per [link](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/alarms#event-onAlarm) and not an alarm ID. I'm unable to remove the listener with a specific alarmID when I have several alarms activated.

Comment: `I'm unable to remove the listener with a specific alarmID`... As far as I can see, listeners are not related to alarm ids. That's why your listener function receives the alarm identifier that triggered the alarm. Edit: I updated my answer to reflect that behavior.

Comment: This is definitively the right way. For several alarms, only one listener is needed. Thanks a lot Max Truxa!